# Where should I locate resource to be loaded by java.util.ResourceBundle?

Tags: java

I came across this piece of code

> ResourceBundle BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("a.b.c.d.E");

I am wondering where I can locate that file to be loaded? I couldn't find the file **a.b.c.d.E** on my disk.

Comment: if you are using this code in eclips then you have to create this in that project dir.

Comment: @devnull: I believe it is a file

Comment: @JayantJadhav I searched the entire project folder recursively and could find that file

Comment: From ResourceBundle doc:"The Java Platform provides two subclasses of ResourceBundle, ListResourceBundle and PropertyResourceBundle, that provide a fairly 
 simple way to create resources. As you saw briefly in a previous example, ListResourceBundle manages its resource as a list of key/value 
 pairs. PropertyResourceBundle uses a properties file to manage its resources. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the getBundle doc of ResourceBundle:

*....getBundle then iterates over the candidate bundle names to find the first one for which it can instantiate an actual resource bundle. For each candidate bundle name, it attempts to create a resource bundle:

First, it attempts to load a class using the candidate bundle name. If such a class can be found and loaded using the specified class loader, is assignment compatible with ResourceBundle, is accessible from ResourceBundle, and can be instantiated, getBundle creates a new instance of this class and uses it as the result resource bundle.

Otherwise, getBundle attempts to locate a property resource file. It generates a path name from the candidate bundle name by replacing all "." characters with "/" and appending the string ".properties". It attempts to find a "resource" with this name using ClassLoader.getResource. (Note that a "resource" in the sense of getResource has nothing to do with the contents of a resource bundle, it is just a container of data, such as a file.) If it finds a "resource", it attempts to create a new PropertyResourceBundle instance from its contents. If successful, this instance becomes the result resource bundle.*

So what I understand from this is:if your

```
a.b.c.d.E
```

is not a class, then it will look for a a property file with path

```
a/b/c/d/E.properties
```